# ng-click requires two clicks for view to update

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I called ng-click like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in filterdata">
  <div ng-click="filter(key,value)">
    {{key}} ::::::: {{value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

and my Controller function looks like this:

```
$scope.filter = function(key,value){
  $location.search(key, value);
  var filter = $location.url();
  service.get(filter).success(function(data) {
    $scope.applicationdata = data.data;
    console.log($scope.applicationdata);
  });
}
```

and my HTML file has `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<div class="resultsa" ng-repeat="data in applicationdata">
        {{data.name}}<hr>
        <div ng-repeat="metadata in data.metadata">
          {{metadata.name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;,&nbsp;&nbsp;{{metadata.pivot.value}}
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The first time I click, my service function is called and my model is updated but my view doesn't update.  When I click a second time, my view properly updates.  Can anyone tell me why this happening?

Comment: Are you using `$http` to get the data? if not try `$scope.$apply()` after populating your data.

Comment: yes i am using $http in my service

Comment: Can you create a plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: Sounds like the digest loop isn't running. Angular watches for certain events to occur (ex. click) and automatically re-evaluates scope bindings. But for things that happen outside of Angular's knowledge, you need to manually trigger the digest loop with `$scope.$apply()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are changing the value of the model after the digest cicle was triggered, and in a different context. For solving this you need to call $scope.$apply() after setting the application data, for triggering another digest cycle.